# How to get geo coordinates of road?

Tags: google-maps, maps, openstreetmap, here-api

I'm trying to create a corridor along a road. Therefore I need some kind of a coordinate set. Currently I'm requesting a route and using it's coordinates. But with this approach I run into problems if there is a long segment, eg. 200km on a highway. If I only use the position of the instructions when getting onto the highway and when exiting it, the corridor may miss some parts of the road since it may not be a straight one.

So what I'd like to do is, query the "major" road coordinates of a road. For now it does not matter if id needs an ID or the road name or any coordinates.

I'm currently working with HERE maps, but if there is any other service which may fulfill my requirement, I'm open to review and test it. I also reviewed google-maps api, but still not found a service or any similar approach. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: the question is not really clear, if you fetch a route, be it google, nokia or OSM stuff like graphhopper the FULL geometry of a route is already included, also per every instruction

Comment: actually this is not the problem. I do get coordinates for each instruction. But if there is for example a segment of 150km Highway there are no more coordinates. Only the ramp positions for entering and exiting the highway. What I want are more coordinates to know the real course of the road, not just two coordinates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you need to obtain the full geometry of the route first, then prune the result down to the coordinates you want.

For both the HERE [7.2 routing API](https://route.cit.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?waypoint0=52.5160%2C13.3779&waypoint1=52.5206%2C13.3862&mode=fastest%3Bcar%3Btraffic%3Aenabled&routeattributes=shape&maneuverattributes=direction%2Cshape&app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg&departure=now) and the [6.2 Enterprise Routing API](https://route.st.nlp.nokia.com/routing/6.2/calculateroute.json?waypoint0=41.9798%2C-87.8801&waypoint1=41.9043%2C-87.9216&mode=fastest%3Btruck%3Btraffic%3Adefault%3B&routeattributes=shape&app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg), If you want to obtain the shape of a route you just need to include the parameter `routeattributes=shape`.

e.g.

```
.../calculateroute.json?waypoint0=lat,lng&waypoint1=lat,lng&mode=fastest:car:traffic:Adefault&routeattributes=shape&app_id=YOR_APPID&app_code=YOUR_TOKEN
```

The full geometry (of routes or manuevers) is not usually returned without the `shape` enum being set.

This is explained in the [API User guide](https://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/routing) as shown:

**routeAttributes**

Define which atrributes are included in the response as part of the data representation of the route. Defaults to `waypoints, summary,summaryByCountry legs, line`s. See also [RouteAttributeType](https://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/enterprise-routing/topics/resource-param-type-route-representation-options.html#type-route-attribute).

Enum [`waypoints | summary | summaryByCountry | shape | boundingBox | legs | notes` ]

The [route shape example](http://developer.here.com/api-explorer#routing/route-from-a-to-b-with-shape) within the API explorer returns :

```
[
"52.5160414,13.3782982",
"52.5163436,13.3782148",
"52.5162363,13.3783329",
"52.5162148,13.3786547",
"52.5162792,13.3795774",
"52.5163651,13.3808541",
"52.5165153,13.3807898",
"52.516644,13.3807361",
"52.5169337,13.3806503",
"52.5181997,13.3804357",
"52.5189185,13.380264",
"52.5189829,13.3811975",
"52.5191653,13.3820879",
"52.5197446,13.3840835",
"52.5201201,13.3851671",
"52.5203025,13.3855319",
"52.52056,13.3859825",
"52.5206485,13.3861105"
],  ... etc.
```

within the response.

Comment: Thanks a lot! this solved my problem. I tried all these parameters yesterday, but nothing seemed to work. Now it works! Thx